# How to load xml file from another server on html file using javascript?

Tags: php, javascript, xml

Webpage error details

User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 5.1; Trident/4.0; FunWebProducts; InfoPath.2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.04506.648; msn OptimizedIE8;ENIN)
Timestamp: Tue, 23 Nov 2010 15:33:31 UTC

Message: Access is denied.

Line: 18
Char: 1
Code: 0
URI: http://www.legacyjobline.com/rating_page.html

Comment: WTF, we can't use the force to deduce your question. Please explain better.

Answer (score 1):

You are going to be severely limited in cross-domain JavaScript. Look into JSONP.

Comment: How to load xml file on html page using javascript?  Xml file is belongs to another server...there is a path issue..to load xml file

Answer (score 0):

Due to security restrictions it is not possible to use Javascript to read xml files from another domain.

Comment: How to load xml file on html page using javascript?  Xml file is belongs to another server...there is a path issue..to load xml file

Answer (score 0):

You are being denied to do that by the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy). Depending on your use case there could be workarounds. Tell us more.

Comment: How to load xml file on html page using javascript?  Xml file is belongs to another server...there is a path issue..to load xml file

Comment: You can't. You have to get the XML-file server-side and publish on the same server as the script is loaded from and then get it from there. There is a draft from W3C that enables cross site XMLHttpRequests but I don't know about adoption. http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest2/

Answer (score 0):

The message is quite clear: "Access is denied". If you really need that XML, you could try to write a PHP script on your local server that reads the XML file and then, from your JavaScript, try to load  your PHP script (which would have to return a application/xml or text/xml or whatever MIME type matches to XML).